# How to improve the peachpie compiler Api performance on C#?

Tags: c#, php, peachpie

I compiled the php code using peachpie compiler on C# but the problem is that after compilation when I call the function it take the much more time then the same function written in C#.

So I want to know can I improve the performance of peachpie compiler context.

Or Is there any we can convert php code to C# code.

I run some benchmark but the difference is big. I also want performance. Benchmarks php run using c#

[image: Benchmarks php run using c#]

```
const string ScriptPath = @"Index.php";
    var fullpath = ScriptPath;

    var ctx = Context.CreateConsole(string.Empty, args);
    var script = Context.DefaultScriptingProvider.CreateScript(new Context.ScriptOptions()
    {

        Context = ctx,
        Location = new Location(fullpath, 0, 0),
        EmitDebugInformation = true,
        IsSubmission = false,
        AdditionalReferences = new string[] {
                typeof(Program).Assembly.Location,
                typeof(Peachpie.Library.Graphics.PhpImage).Assembly.Location,
                typeof(Peachpie.Library.MySql.MySql).Assembly.Location,
                typeof(Peachpie.Library.Network.CURLFunctions).Assembly.Location,
            }
    }, File.ReadAllText(fullpath));
    try
    {
        var res = script.Evaluate(ctx, ctx.Globals, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    var res1 =  _context.Call("Multiply", 123, 123,123);
```

C# Method

```
 public int MultiplyCSharp(int num1, int num2, int num3)
    {
        var sum = num1 * num2 * num3;
        return sum;
    }
```

php Function

```
function Multiply($num1, $num2, $num3 ) {
$sum = $num1 * $num2 * $num3 ;
return $sum;}
```

Comment: I don't speak for the Peachpie team, but I'm pretty certain their current benchmark goal is to make PHP faster, and not to compete with native C#.

Comment: Yes You are right. Actually my requirement are same performance or almost same as normal C#. I have multiple functions in php now I have two options. Compile those functions using peachpie C#. or rewrite those functions in C#. the problem with peach pie approach is performance. and the problem with 2nd option is that there around 300 functions which almost change their logic daily so I cant write them manually. So If anyone know how to increase peachpie _context.call performance or any converter that convert the php code to C#.

Comment: I don't really know much about Peacepie, but do you know if it has opcache support? I'd be curious how PHP native with full opcache compares to PHP compiled to C#. I just ran your native PHP function 132,111 times and it takes 0.0065 seconds on my desktop computer.

Comment: No It don't have support for opcache

Comment: I think Peachpie is an interesting project, and it would be wonderful if more people contributed to it to make it better, just like what Mono did for .Net. That said, even though it is production-ready, I don't think I would put it in competition with C#, specifically because it sounds like the optimizations aren't available. If you have functions that need to be run in a tight-loop, and/or thousands of times per request, I would stick to native PHP or native C#.